# Java create listener on DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I'm building a Java Swing application with Java. I have my `JPanel` that have a `JTable` with a custom `TableModel`. Now I want to know if it is possible to register an envet then if in table model I start this event, the `JPanel` intercept this event and execute a method.

This is my `TableModel`:

```
public class MyTableModelScontriniArticoli extends defaultTableModel {

    private static final String[] columnNames = {"Cod.Prod.", "Descrizione", 
            "Qta", "Prezzo cad.", "% Sconto", "Prezzo Tot"};

    public HashMap<String, ArticoliScontrini> mappaArticoli = 
            new HashMap<String, ArticoliScontrini>();

    private static NumberFormat decimalFormatter2 = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

    private Integer numeroPz = 0;

    public Boolean gestisciTagliaColore;

    public MyTableModelScontriniArticoli() {

    }

    public MyTableModelScontriniArticoli(boolean gestisciTagliaColore) {
        super(columnNames, 1);    // 10 righe iniziali (vuote)
        mappaArticoli = new HashMap<String, ArticoliScontrini>();
        this.gestisciTagliaColore = gestisciTagliaColore;
    }

    public MyTableModelScontriniArticoli(String[] columnnames2, int i) {
        super(columnnames2, 1);    // 10 righe iniziali (vuote)
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        super.setValueAt(aValue, rowIndex, columnIndex);
        if (columnIndex == 2) {
            //TO DO METHOD 2
            //LAUNCH EVENT
        } else if (columnIndex == 3) {
            //TO DO METHOD 3
            //LAUNCH EVENT
        } else if (columnIndex == 4) {
            //TO DO METHOD 4
            //LAUNCH EVENT
        } else if (columnIndex == 6) {
            //TO DO METHOD 6
            //LAUNCH EVENT
        }
    }

}
```

My `tableModel` extends `DefaultTableModel`. Now I override `setValueAt` method and I want that after execute a condition I can run an event and the `JPanel` that contains my `TableModel` can intercept it and execute some method.

Answer (score 0):

ok, think I got it: 
Add your TableModel to your table

```
 jTable1.setModel(new MyTableModelScontriniArticoli());
```

then add an TableModelListener to your table.  It will react on 'fireTableChanged' calls.

```
jTable1.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
          //do some event stuff
  });
```

Your setValueAt method:

```
  switch(columnIndex){
        case 2: /*do your stuff*/ break;
        case 3: /*do your stuff*/ break;
        case 4: /*do your stuff*/ break;
    }

 //this.fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this, rowIndex,rowIndex,columnIndex)); 
 fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
```

Comment: ok, but I want to generate this event after that the metohd setValueAt is execute.